# An expression for " linking something that has happened to a particular reason or circumtance"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

How to express linking an unfavourable incident that has happened to a particular reason or circumstance?

For example: *A team lost a competition and is being consoled by their coach. Their coach consoling his team by linking the lost to their lack of experience.*

How to describe what coach is doing?

Comment: Mr G admitted that there were aspects of the Police Dept.'s work that needed changing. (_Room_ in the sense of _space, scope_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that some (not necessarily unfortunate) occurrence happened due to something is ***ascribing*** the occurrence to something.

> The coach consoled his team by ***ascribing*** the loss to their lack of
>   experience.

ODO:

> **[ascribe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ascribe)**
>   *VERB*   [WITH OBJECT]
>   **(ascribe something to)**
>   **1** Regard something as being due to (a cause)
>
> ‘he ascribed Jane's short temper to her upset stomach’
>
> ‘The AP obituary says it was lung cancer and ascribes the disease to
>   his smoking history, both of which I think are incorrect.’